# Issue with Nested Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some dictionary a.

```
a = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
```

And I had some dictionary b with a as a value

```
b = {1: a}
```

If I print b, change a then print b again, for example:

```
print(b)
a[1] = 'd'
print(b)
```

I get the following:

```
{'a': {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}}
{'a': {1: 'd', 2: 'b'}}
```

Why does this happen? Does the dict automatically update if you set a value to a variable and then update it? Thanks.

Comment: No.  The value in dictionary `b` points to the variable `a`.  Any change to the latter will be reflected in the former.  If you want them to be separate, just copy the dictionary:  `b = {1: a.copy()}`

Comment: Note that `a.copy()` is a shallow copy. Mutations to `a.copy()`'s values will be visible through `a`.

Comment: Do this. `print( id(a) ); print( id(b['a']) )` See that they are both the same object? So if you change the object via either reference then no matter how you access that object, it will be changed. See also [this explanation](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

If you write,

```
b = {1: a}
```

the value of 1, that is `a`, refers to the dictionary that you previously defined. So whatever change that you make to dictionary `a` will be reflected in dictionary `b`. The literal `a` in dictionary `b` is just a reference object to dictionary `a`.

Answer (score -2):

`a`, a dict, holds reference to the dictionary `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}`. any changes that you make reflect in the dictionary.

> since everything in python is an object, implies that every variable
>   is just a reference.

Hence due to the change in dict after the `first print(b)` the `second print(b)` is different.